# When generating java sources with maven-jaxb2-plugin, how to enable setters for collections?

Tags: java, xjc, maven-jaxb2-plugin

I am generating POJOs from XSD schemas using the maven-jab2-plugin. My generated classes don't have setters for any fields that are collections.  How do I generate setters for collections?

Can anyone explain the reasoning for setters to not be enabled by default?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use the [Setters plugin](http://confluence.highsource.org/display/J2B/Setters+Plugin) included in JAXB2-Basics, as documented [here](http://confluence.highsource.org/display/J2B/JAXB2+Basics+Plugins).

I've copy-pasted their usage example (and modified it to show setters specifically):

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.jvnet.jaxb2.maven2</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-jaxb2-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>0.7.0</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <goals>
                <goal>generate</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
    <configuration>
        <args>
            <arg>-Xsetters</arg>
        </args>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.jvnet.jaxb2_commons</groupId>
                <artifactId>jaxb2-basics</artifactId>
                <version><!-- Current version --></version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

And include the JAXB2 Basics Runtime package in your dependencies:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jvnet.jaxb2_commons</groupId>
    <artifactId>jaxb2-basics-runtime</artifactId>
    <version><!-- Current version --></version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: After spending too long googling, I am asking/answering to document the answer.  I could find lots of references to the xjc collection-setter-injector plugin, but couldn't seem to get anything working. (I would just get "Unrecognized parameter -Xcollection-setter-injector" and never figured out how I was supposed to include/point to the correct dependency.)  JAXB2-Basics worked with no hassle.

Comment: This plugin interferes with [com.github.jaxb-xew-plugin](https://github.com/dmak/jaxb-xew-plugin/issues/16) (or vice versa)...

Answer (score 1):

For generating setter for collection I have found only a solution that works for me. You have to add dependency to **org.andromda.thirdparty.jaxb2_commons**. However, this solution works for **jaxb2-maven-plugin** version **2.5.0**, for version **2.3.1** doesn't work.
Here's an example:

```
 <plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>jaxb2-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.5.0</version>
    <dependencies>
      <dependency>
         <groupId>org.andromda.thirdparty.jaxb2_commons</groupId>
         <artifactId>collection-setter-injector</artifactId>
         <version>1.0</version>
      </dependency>
   </dependencies>
   <executions>
      <execution>
             ......
       </execution>
    </executions>
    <configuration>
       <sources>
             ......
       </sources>
       <arguments>-Xcollection-setter-injector</arguments>
       <clearOutputDir>false</clearOutputDir>
       <extension>true</extension>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```