# Setter generation for List using JAXB

Tags: java, jaxb

I use `JAXB` for mapping `XML` configuration to Java object. This configuration could be edited from `UI`, that's why in order to transfer it to UI and vice versa. I definitely need to unmarshall `json` into Java object. Hence it's required to have setter method for `List`.

How to generate setter method for List property for POJO class using JAXB?

Comment: possible duplicate of [When generating java sources with maven-jaxb2-plugin, how to enable setters for collections?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13335116/when-generating-java-sources-with-maven-jaxb2-plugin-how-to-enable-setters-for)

Answer (score 0):

For security reasons setter are not generated for List objects.

```
/**
 * Gets the value of the dateIntervals property.
 * 
 * <p>
 * This accessor method returns a reference to the live list,
 * not a snapshot. Therefore any modification you make to the
 * returned list will be present inside the JAXB object.
 * This is why there is not a <CODE>set</CODE> method for the dateIntervals property.
 * 
 * <p>
 * For example, to add a new item, do as follows:
 * <pre>
 *    getDateIntervals().add(newItem);
 * </pre>
 * 
 * 
 * <p>
 * Objects of the following type(s) are allowed in the list
 * {@link DateInterval }
 * 
 * 
 */
```

Answer (score -1):

For that you need create variable of List.The setter getter methods for this List variable are as below.

```
package foo.bar.me.too;

import java.util.List;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

@XmlRootElement(name="VisitorDataList")
public class visitordatalist {


    List<visitordata> vstd;

    @XmlElement(name="VisitorData")
    public List<visitordata> getVstd() {
        return vstd;
    }

    public void setVstd(List<visitordata> vstd) {
        this.vstd = vstd;
    }   

}
```

Comment: I'm using xjc for class generation.

Comment: Dosent Make sense when using Auto Generated XJC Classes